# Unable to access the props directly in Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have stored the data in a file (details.js) as a JavaScript Object, then I'm trying to pass it as a prop from MainComponent to ChildComponent. Well the prop is accessible in ChildComponent but I could access it with `props.ChildDetails[0].name` instead of `props.name` directly as shown in the [Official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

What am i missing?

details.js

```js
export const DETAILS=[
    {
        id:0,
        profile:'/assests/images/john.png',
        name:'John Doe',
    }
]
```

MainComponent.js

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Child from './ChildComponent';
import {DETAILS} from '../Shared/details';
function MainComponent(){
    return(
        <>
            <Child ChildDetails={DETAILS}/>
        </>
    );
}
export default MainComponent;
```

ChildComponent.js

```js
import React from 'react';
function ChildComponent(props){
    console.log(props.name) //Output:undefined
    console.log(props.ChildDetails[0].name) //Output:John Doe
    return(
        <div></div>
    );
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

Comment: Your `details` is array. When you pass it as object to props it stays the same - e.g. - array. Transfrom it to the object if you need `<Child ChildDetails={DETAILS[0]}/>`

Comment: `<Child name={DETAILS[0].name} />` or `<Child {...DETAILS[0]} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Details is object.
Try something like:

```
function ChildComponent({ ChildDetails }){
    const { name } = ChildDetails[0]
    ...
}
```

That's not even React. That's JavaScript

**Edit**. Oops. People said that's an array. I thought it's just an object. Fixed code a bit

Answer (score 1):

here is where you passed the object

```
<Child ChildDetails={DETAILS}/>
```

and here is how you tried to use it

```
console.log(props.name) //Output:undefined
```

since you defined the name as `ChildDetails` there is no such thing as props.name instead you must say

```
console.log(props.ChildDetails)
```

and if you want to get access to an `name` you should declare the index if not react does not know which index you want to use, so as you did before

```
 props.ChildDetails[0].name
```